# Sqlalchemy joining two tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The title is terrible, I am sorry for that but I couldn't think of anything that would describe the situation.

I have two tables such as the following:

> *Readings* table has a foreign key which is connected to the ID of *Weather stations' readings*

**Weather stations' readings**

```
-------------------------------------
| Id1 | StationId1 | Location | Time |
| Id2 | StationId2 | Location | Time |
|      ...                           |
--------------------------------------
```

**Readings**

```
-----------------------------
| Id   | Foreign | Readings  |
| RId1 | Id1     | Reading 1 |
| RId2 | Id1     | Reading 2 |
| RId3 | Id1     | Reading 3 |
| RId4 | Id2     | Reading 4 |
| RId5 | Id2     | Reading 5 |
| RId6 | Id1     | Reading 6 |
|      ...                   |
------------------------------
```

Every station is already known. There are hundreds of them. Every time the readings are collected, there will be a one entry to *Weather stations' readings* table and several entries to the *Readings* table. What I want to do is to get the readings for that particular station entry for a given reading ID.

For example, I have **RId2**. I need to get the following table:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id1 | StationId1 | Location | Time | RId1 | Id1     | Reading 1 |
| Id1 | StationId1 | Location | Time | RId2 | Id1     | Reading 2 |
| Id1 | StationId1 | Location | Time | RId3 | Id1     | Reading 3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*NOTE:* The following code is sort of like a pseudo code. I do not use this code, neither this table really exists. I do not have the right to share that so this will have to do.

```
class StationReadings(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'StationReadings'
    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    StationId = Column(Integer) # This normally has a foreign key too
    Location = Column(String)
    Time = Column(DateTime)
    Readings = relationship("Readings")


class Readings(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Readings'
    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Station = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('StationReadings.Id'))
    Readings = Column(Float)
```

I believe something like this can be used to enhance it too:

```
primaryjoin="and_(StationReadings.Id==Readings.Station)"
```

Comment: The relationship you have should work as is, without an explicit primaryjoin. Could you elaborate what you're after?